# Tensorflow Attribute Error: 'method' object has no attribute '_from_serialized'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a model in Tensorflow and get the error:

`Attribute Error: 'method' object has no attribute '_from_serialized'`

This is code that I have copied and seen work.

It seems that it has something to do with the compatibility of my tensorflow version and python version. I'm able to run other models, but this error seems to occur when I'm trying to track custom metrics.

What is the most recent compatible versions of Tensorflow-GPU and python can that run models while tracking custom metrics?

I've checked the table that Tensorflow provides and these versions should be compatible.

My current version of Tensorflow is 2.10.0
Python version is 3.9.6.

Is there something else that might cause this errors. I've created multiple environments with different versions and still receive this error.

```
import os
import pickle

from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, ReLU, BatchNormalization, \
    Flatten, Dense, Reshape, Conv2DTranspose, Activation, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class VAE:
    """
    VAE represents a Deep Convolutional variational autoencoder architecture
    with mirrored encoder and decoder components.
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 input_shape,
                 conv_filters,
                 conv_kernels,
                 conv_strides,
                 latent_space_dim):
        self.input_shape = input_shape # [28, 28, 1]
        self.conv_filters = conv_filters # [2, 4, 8]
        self.conv_kernels = conv_kernels # [3, 5, 3]
        self.conv_strides = conv_strides # [1, 2, 2]
        self.latent_space_dim = latent_space_dim # 2
        self.reconstruction_loss_weight = 1000

        self.encoder = None
        self.decoder = None
        self.model = None

        self._num_conv_layers = len(conv_filters)
        self._shape_before_bottleneck = None
        self._model_input = None

        self._build()

    def summary(self):
        self.encoder.summary()
        self.decoder.summary()
        self.model.summary()

    def compile(self, learning_rate=0.0001):
        optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                           loss=self._calculate_combined_loss,
                           metrics=[self._calculate_reconstruction_loss,
                                    self._calculate_kl_loss])

    def train(self, x_train, batch_size, num_epochs):
        self.model.fit(x_train,
                       x_train,
                       batch_size=batch_size,
                       epochs=num_epochs,
                       shuffle=True)

    def save(self, save_folder="."):
        self._create_folder_if_it_doesnt_exist(save_folder)
        self._save_parameters(save_folder)
        self._save_weights(save_folder)

    def load_weights(self, weights_path):
        self.model.load_weights(weights_path)

    def reconstruct(self, images):
        latent_representations = self.encoder.predict(images)
        reconstructed_images = self.decoder.predict(latent_representations)
        return reconstructed_images, latent_representations

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, save_folder="."):
        parameters_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "parameters.pkl")
        with open(parameters_path, "rb") as f:
            parameters = pickle.load(f)
        autoencoder = VAE(*parameters)
        weights_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "weights.h5")
        autoencoder.load_weights(weights_path)
        return autoencoder

    def _calculate_combined_loss(self, y_target, y_predicted):
        reconstruction_loss = self._calculate_reconstruction_loss(y_target, y_predicted)
        kl_loss = self._calculate_kl_loss(y_target, y_predicted)
        combined_loss = self.reconstruction_loss_weight * reconstruction_loss\
                                                         + kl_loss
        return combined_loss

    def _calculate_reconstruction_loss(self, y_target, y_predicted):
        error = y_target - y_predicted
        reconstruction_loss = K.mean(K.square(error), axis=[1, 2, 3])
        return reconstruction_loss

    def _calculate_kl_loss(self, y_target, y_predicted):
        kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + self.log_variance - K.square(self.mu) -
                               K.exp(self.log_variance), axis=1)
        return kl_loss

    def _create_folder_if_it_doesnt_exist(self, folder):
        if not os.path.exists(folder):
            os.makedirs(folder)

    def _save_parameters(self, save_folder):
        parameters = [
            self.input_shape,
            self.conv_filters,
            self.conv_kernels,
            self.conv_strides,
            self.latent_space_dim
        ]
        save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "parameters.pkl")
        with open(save_path, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(parameters, f)

    def _save_weights(self, save_folder):
        save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "weights.h5")
        self.model.save_weights(save_path)

    def _build(self):
        self._build_encoder()
        self._build_decoder()
        self._build_autoencoder()

    def _build_autoencoder(self):
        model_input = self._model_input
        model_output = self.decoder(self.encoder(model_input))
        self.model = Model(model_input, model_output, name="autoencoder")

    def _build_decoder(self):
        decoder_input = self._add_decoder_input()
        dense_layer = self._add_dense_layer(decoder_input)
        reshape_layer = self._add_reshape_layer(dense_layer)
        conv_transpose_layers = self._add_conv_transpose_layers(reshape_layer)
        decoder_output = self._add_decoder_output(conv_transpose_layers)
        self.decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_output, name="decoder")

    def _add_decoder_input(self):
        return Input(shape=self.latent_space_dim, name="decoder_input")

    def _add_dense_layer(self, decoder_input):
        num_neurons = np.prod(self._shape_before_bottleneck) # [1, 2, 4] -> 8
        dense_layer = Dense(num_neurons, name="decoder_dense")(decoder_input)
        return dense_layer

    def _add_reshape_layer(self, dense_layer):
        return Reshape(self._shape_before_bottleneck)(dense_layer)

    def _add_conv_transpose_layers(self, x):
        """Add conv transpose blocks."""
        # loop through all the conv layers in reverse order and stop at the
        # first layer
        for layer_index in reversed(range(1, self._num_conv_layers)):
            x = self._add_conv_transpose_layer(layer_index, x)
        return x

    def _add_conv_transpose_layer(self, layer_index, x):
        layer_num = self._num_conv_layers - layer_index
        conv_transpose_layer = Conv2DTranspose(
            filters=self.conv_filters[layer_index],
            kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[layer_index],
            strides=self.conv_strides[layer_index],
            padding="same",
            name=f"decoder_conv_transpose_layer_{layer_num}"
        )
        x = conv_transpose_layer(x)
        x = ReLU(name=f"decoder_relu_{layer_num}")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(name=f"decoder_bn_{layer_num}")(x)
        return x

    def _add_decoder_output(self, x):
        conv_transpose_layer = Conv2DTranspose(
            filters=1,
            kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[0],
            strides=self.conv_strides[0],
            padding="same",
            name=f"decoder_conv_transpose_layer_{self._num_conv_layers}"
        )
        x = conv_transpose_layer(x)
        output_layer = Activation("sigmoid", name="sigmoid_layer")(x)
        return output_layer

    def _build_encoder(self):
        encoder_input = self._add_encoder_input()
        conv_layers = self._add_conv_layers(encoder_input)
        bottleneck = self._add_bottleneck(conv_layers)
        self._model_input = encoder_input
        self.encoder = Model(encoder_input, bottleneck, name="encoder")

    def _add_encoder_input(self):
        return Input(shape=self.input_shape, name="encoder_input")

    def _add_conv_layers(self, encoder_input):
        """Create all convolutional blocks in encoder."""
        x = encoder_input
        for layer_index in range(self._num_conv_layers):
            x = self._add_conv_layer(layer_index, x)
        return x

    def _add_conv_layer(self, layer_index, x):
        """Add a convolutional block to a graph of layers, consisting of
        conv 2d + ReLU + batch normalization.
        """
        layer_number = layer_index + 1
        conv_layer = Conv2D(
            filters=self.conv_filters[layer_index],
            kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[layer_index],
            strides=self.conv_strides[layer_index],
            padding="same",
            name=f"encoder_conv_layer_{layer_number}"
        )
        x = conv_layer(x)
        x = ReLU(name=f"encoder_relu_{layer_number}")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(name=f"encoder_bn_{layer_number}")(x)
        return x

    def _add_bottleneck(self, x):
        """Flatten data and add bottleneck with Guassian sampling (Dense
        layer).
        """
        self._shape_before_bottleneck = K.int_shape(x)[1:]
        x = Flatten()(x)
        self.mu = Dense(self.latent_space_dim, name="mu")(x)
        self.log_variance = Dense(self.latent_space_dim,
                                  name="log_variance")(x)

        def sample_point_from_normal_distribution(args):
            mu, log_variance = args
            epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(self.mu), mean=0.,
                                      stddev=1.)
            sampled_point = mu + K.exp(log_variance / 2) * epsilon
            return sampled_point

        x = Lambda(sample_point_from_normal_distribution,
                   name="encoder_output")([self.mu, self.log_variance])
        return x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    autoencoder = VAE(
        input_shape=(28, 28, 1),
        conv_filters=(32, 64, 64, 64),
        conv_kernels=(3, 3, 3, 3),
        conv_strides=(1, 2, 2, 1),
        latent_space_dim=2
    )
    autoencoder.summary()
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0005
BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 100


def load_mnist():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape + (1,))
    x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))

    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test


def train(x_train, learning_rate, batch_size, epochs):
    autoencoder = VAE(
        input_shape=(28, 28, 1),
        conv_filters=(32, 64, 64, 64),
        conv_kernels=(3, 3, 3, 3),
        conv_strides=(1, 2, 2, 1),
        latent_space_dim=2
    )
    autoencoder.summary()
    autoencoder.compile(learning_rate)
    autoencoder.train(x_train, batch_size, epochs)
    return autoencoder


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x_train, _, _, _ = load_mnist()
    autoencoder = train(x_train[:10000], LEARNING_RATE, BATCH_SIZE, EPOCHS)
    autoencoder.save("model")
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a mompatibility error? Maybe it is a wrong assignment to a variable. Some more backtrace could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attribute error here is raised because you can't set any attribute on a method object i.e;

```py
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print("bar")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Foo().bar.baz = 1
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): line 7, in <module>
    Foo().bar.baz = 1
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'baz'
```

When collecting the metric information in `training_utils_v1`, the metrics specified when the model is compiled (`model.compile(..., metrics=[..])`) are iterated over, and for each metric, the attribute `_from_serialized` is set:

```py
    for i, metrics in enumerate(nested_metrics):
        metrics_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
        for metric in metrics:
            metric_name = get_metric_name(metric, is_weighted)
            metric_fn = get_metric_function(
                metric, output_shape=output_shapes[i], loss_fn=loss_fns[i]
            )
            metric_fn._from_serialized = from_serialized
```

In the example provided, two metrics are supplied to `model.compile`, and each are methods of the `VAE` class:

```py
    def compile(self, learning_rate=0.0001):
        optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                           loss=self._calculate_combined_loss,
                           metrics=[self._calculate_reconstruction_loss,
                                    self._calculate_kl_loss])
```

To test this, observe if `metrics` is entirely omitted, training will start successfully.

One of the metrics supplied, `_calculate_reconstruction_loss` is a method which does not need to be a method, as it does not refer to `self` in the body:

```py
    def _calculate_reconstruction_loss(self, y_target, y_predicted):
        error = y_target - y_predicted
        reconstruction_loss = K.mean(K.square(error), axis=[1, 2, 3])
        return reconstruction_loss
```

So that can be moved outside of the class and made into a function (some IDEs will recommend this to you in the form of a message to the effect of "Make function from method"):

```py
    def _calculate_reconstruction_loss(y_target, y_predicted):
        error = y_target - y_predicted
        reconstruction_loss = K.mean(K.square(error), axis=[1, 2, 3])
        return reconstruction_loss
```

The compile statement can then be revised:

```py
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                           loss=self._calculate_combined_loss,
                           metrics=[_calculate_reconstruction_loss,
                                    self._calculate_kl_loss])
```

The same exception will appear, since we're still referring to a method in the call (`self.calculate_kl_loss`) but if `self.calculate_kl_loss` is omitted, the training will start successfully:

```py
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                           loss=self._calculate_combined_loss,
                           metrics=[_calculate_reconstruction_loss])
```

For completeness, reviewing what `self.calculate_kl_loss` is doing, it's a bit more tricky, but we can successfully use it as a metric by converting it into a function which takes a single argument `model`, which returns another function that takes arbitrary number of arguments (`*args`) such that it can be used both as a metric (which always expects a function of two arguments) and utilized in the loss function:

```py
def calculate_kl_loss(model):
    # wrap `_calculate_kl_loss` such that it takes the model as an argument,
    # returns a function which can take arbitrary number of arguments
    # (for compatibility with `metrics` and utility in the loss function)
    # and returns the kl loss
    def _calculate_kl_loss(*args):
        kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + model.log_variance - K.square(model.mu) -
                               K.exp(model.log_variance), axis=1)
        return kl_loss
    return _calculate_kl_loss
```

With these revisions, when training is started, the output is:

```
Epoch 1/100
10000/10000 [==============================] - 43s 4ms/sample - loss: 89.4243 - _calculate_reconstruction_loss: 0.0833 - _calculate_kl_loss: 6.1707
Epoch 2/100
10000/10000 [==============================] - 46s 5ms/sample - loss: 69.0131 - _calculate_reconstruction_loss: 0.0619 - _calculate_kl_loss: 7.1129
```

The entire snippet with revisions detailed above is:

```py
import os
import pickle

from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, ReLU, BatchNormalization, \
    Flatten, Dense, Reshape, Conv2DTranspose, Activation, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution

disable_eager_execution()


def _calculate_reconstruction_loss(y_target, y_predicted):
    error = y_target - y_predicted
    reconstruction_loss = K.mean(K.square(error), axis=[1, 2, 3])
    return reconstruction_loss


def calculate_kl_loss(model):
    # wrap `_calculate_kl_loss` such that it takes the model as an argument,
    # returns a function which can take arbitrary number of arguments
    # (for compatibility with `metrics` and utility in the loss function)
    # and returns the kl loss
    def _calculate_kl_loss(*args):
        kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1 + model.log_variance - K.square(model.mu) -
                               K.exp(model.log_variance), axis=1)
        return kl_loss
    return _calculate_kl_loss


class VAE:
    """
    VAE represents a Deep Convolutional variational autoencoder architecture
    with mirrored encoder and decoder components.
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 input_shape,
                 conv_filters,
                 conv_kernels,
                 conv_strides,
                 latent_space_dim):
        self.input_shape = input_shape # [28, 28, 1]
        self.conv_filters = conv_filters # [2, 4, 8]
        self.conv_kernels = conv_kernels # [3, 5, 3]
        self.conv_strides = conv_strides # [1, 2, 2]
        self.latent_space_dim = latent_space_dim # 2
        self.reconstruction_loss_weight = 1000

        self.encoder = None
        self.decoder = None
        self.model = None

        self._num_conv_layers = len(conv_filters)
        self._shape_before_bottleneck = None
        self._model_input = None

        self._build()

    def summary(self):
        self.encoder.summary()
        self.decoder.summary()
        self.model.summary()

    def compile(self, learning_rate=0.0001):
        optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
        self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                           loss=self._calculate_combined_loss,
                           metrics=[_calculate_reconstruction_loss,
                                    calculate_kl_loss(self)])

    def train(self, x_train, batch_size, num_epochs):
        self.model.fit(x_train,
                       x_train,
                       batch_size=batch_size,
                       epochs=num_epochs,
                       shuffle=True)

    def save(self, save_folder="."):
        self._create_folder_if_it_doesnt_exist(save_folder)
        self._save_parameters(save_folder)
        self._save_weights(save_folder)

    def load_weights(self, weights_path):
        self.model.load_weights(weights_path)

    def reconstruct(self, images):
        latent_representations = self.encoder.predict(images)
        reconstructed_images = self.decoder.predict(latent_representations)
        return reconstructed_images, latent_representations

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, save_folder="."):
        parameters_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "parameters.pkl")
        with open(parameters_path, "rb") as f:
            parameters = pickle.load(f)
        autoencoder = VAE(*parameters)
        weights_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "weights.h5")
        autoencoder.load_weights(weights_path)
        return autoencoder

    def _calculate_combined_loss(self, y_target, y_predicted):
        reconstruction_loss = _calculate_reconstruction_loss(y_target, y_predicted)
        kl_loss = calculate_kl_loss(self)()
        combined_loss = self.reconstruction_loss_weight * reconstruction_loss\
                                                         + kl_loss
        return combined_loss

    def _create_folder_if_it_doesnt_exist(self, folder):
        if not os.path.exists(folder):
            os.makedirs(folder)

    def _save_parameters(self, save_folder):
        parameters = [
            self.input_shape,
            self.conv_filters,
            self.conv_kernels,
            self.conv_strides,
            self.latent_space_dim
        ]
        save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "parameters.pkl")
        with open(save_path, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(parameters, f)

    def _save_weights(self, save_folder):
        save_path = os.path.join(save_folder, "weights.h5")
        self.model.save_weights(save_path)

    def _build(self):
        self._build_encoder()
        self._build_decoder()
        self._build_autoencoder()

    def _build_autoencoder(self):
        model_input = self._model_input
        model_output = self.decoder(self.encoder(model_input))
        self.model = Model(model_input, model_output, name="autoencoder")

    def _build_decoder(self):
        decoder_input = self._add_decoder_input()
        dense_layer = self._add_dense_layer(decoder_input)
        reshape_layer = self._add_reshape_layer(dense_layer)
        conv_transpose_layers = self._add_conv_transpose_layers(reshape_layer)
        decoder_output = self._add_decoder_output(conv_transpose_layers)
        self.decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoder_output, name="decoder")

    def _add_decoder_input(self):
        return Input(shape=self.latent_space_dim, name="decoder_input")

    def _add_dense_layer(self, decoder_input):
        num_neurons = np.prod(self._shape_before_bottleneck) # [1, 2, 4] -> 8
        dense_layer = Dense(num_neurons, name="decoder_dense")(decoder_input)
        return dense_layer

    def _add_reshape_layer(self, dense_layer):
        return Reshape(self._shape_before_bottleneck)(dense_layer)

    def _add_conv_transpose_layers(self, x):
        """Add conv transpose blocks."""
        # loop through all the conv layers in reverse order and stop at the
        # first layer
        for layer_index in reversed(range(1, self._num_conv_layers)):
            x = self._add_conv_transpose_layer(layer_index, x)
        return x

    def _add_conv_transpose_layer(self, layer_index, x):
        layer_num = self._num_conv_layers - layer_index
        conv_transpose_layer = Conv2DTranspose(
            filters=self.conv_filters[layer_index],
            kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[layer_index],
            strides=self.conv_strides[layer_index],
            padding="same",
            name=f"decoder_conv_transpose_layer_{layer_num}"
        )
        x = conv_transpose_layer(x)
        x = ReLU(name=f"decoder_relu_{layer_num}")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(name=f"decoder_bn_{layer_num}")(x)
        return x

    def _add_decoder_output(self, x):
        conv_transpose_layer = Conv2DTranspose(
            filters=1,
            kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[0],
            strides=self.conv_strides[0],
            padding="same",
            name=f"decoder_conv_transpose_layer_{self._num_conv_layers}"
        )
        x = conv_transpose_layer(x)
        output_layer = Activation("sigmoid", name="sigmoid_layer")(x)
        return output_layer

    def _build_encoder(self):
        encoder_input = self._add_encoder_input()
        conv_layers = self._add_conv_layers(encoder_input)
        bottleneck = self._add_bottleneck(conv_layers)
        self._model_input = encoder_input
        self.encoder = Model(encoder_input, bottleneck, name="encoder")

    def _add_encoder_input(self):
        return Input(shape=self.input_shape, name="encoder_input")

    def _add_conv_layers(self, encoder_input):
        """Create all convolutional blocks in encoder."""
        x = encoder_input
        for layer_index in range(self._num_conv_layers):
            x = self._add_conv_layer(layer_index, x)
        return x

    def _add_conv_layer(self, layer_index, x):
        """Add a convolutional block to a graph of layers, consisting of
        conv 2d + ReLU + batch normalization.
        """
        layer_number = layer_index + 1
        conv_layer = Conv2D(
            filters=self.conv_filters[layer_index],
            kernel_size=self.conv_kernels[layer_index],
            strides=self.conv_strides[layer_index],
            padding="same",
            name=f"encoder_conv_layer_{layer_number}"
        )
        x = conv_layer(x)
        x = ReLU(name=f"encoder_relu_{layer_number}")(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(name=f"encoder_bn_{layer_number}")(x)
        return x

    def _add_bottleneck(self, x):
        """Flatten data and add bottleneck with Guassian sampling (Dense
        layer).
        """
        self._shape_before_bottleneck = K.int_shape(x)[1:]
        x = Flatten()(x)
        self.mu = Dense(self.latent_space_dim, name="mu")(x)
        self.log_variance = Dense(self.latent_space_dim,
                                  name="log_variance")(x)

        def sample_point_from_normal_distribution(args):
            mu, log_variance = args
            epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(self.mu), mean=0.,
                                      stddev=1.)
            sampled_point = mu + K.exp(log_variance / 2) * epsilon
            return sampled_point

        x = Lambda(sample_point_from_normal_distribution,
                   name="encoder_output")([self.mu, self.log_variance])
        return x


LEARNING_RATE = 0.0005
BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 100


def load_mnist():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

    x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape + (1,))
    x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))

    return x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test


def train(x_train, learning_rate, batch_size, epochs):
    autoencoder = VAE(
        input_shape=(28, 28, 1),
        conv_filters=(32, 64, 64, 64),
        conv_kernels=(3, 3, 3, 3),
        conv_strides=(1, 2, 2, 1),
        latent_space_dim=2
    )
    autoencoder.summary()
    autoencoder.compile(learning_rate)
    autoencoder.train(x_train, batch_size, epochs)
    return autoencoder


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x_train, _, _, _ = load_mnist()
    autoencoder = train(x_train[:10000], LEARNING_RATE, BATCH_SIZE, EPOCHS)
    autoencoder.save("model")
```

Comment: You can set attributes on functions but5 not on bound methods. Ha. I didn't know that.

Comment: It works! Very well explained, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to call the method which should return the value the other method `_from_serialized()`.

You did not specify your code but what the error infers is this:

```py
# you probably passed this
my_method._from_serialized()
# instead of
my_method()._from_serialized()
```

Otherwise if it's an error regarding the loading of a model I found this [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13590#issuecomment-723438617) on github that may help you.
To quote it:

> I have the same problem in Keras version: 2.3.0 and in my case, this behaviour can be fixed by using **tf.keras.models.load_model** instead of direct **load_model**. I also change every import statement from 'keras' to 'tensorflow.keras' to avoid crash between old keras and new tensorflow.keras. hope it helps, cheers.

Comment: I've added the code to my post. I'm using the MNIST dataset, loading it in they way mentioned in the post. I never explicitly call _from_serialized(), this is something Tensorflow is calling the background.